# Changing Root EBS volume from Volume created from EBS Snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created snapshot, from volume(Root volume).

After one day, I need to set my snapshot as root volume.

I followed these steps :

- For that I created a volume from snapshot.
- My working instance was stopped.
- Detached root volume of my instance
- Attached the volume generated from snapshot as /dev/sda1
- and then instance started

---

I have a problem while starting my instance, it was **not starting** and no errors occurred.

Can you guys please check the process and let me know if anything else required

Comment: Yo say no errors occurred. What does the instance log say? You can read the log from your AWS console. Sometimes it's a problem with fstab trying to mount volumes that aren't attached to the instance and/or have a different mount point.

Comment: where can I found log files in aws console ??

Comment: Right click on an instance's name http://imgur.com/XX59P4O